# Revoke firebase admin credentials certificate

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam

On a server firestore admin is accessed using python:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
cred = credentials.Certificate('myfile.json')
```

myfile.json has been added to a git repo so now I'm wondering if there is a way to revoke it and create a new one?

Following firebase tutorials it's supposed to be a service account, however there is no old service account on google cloud to revoke.

myfile.json was created months ago so there is no way to know how it was created (as when doing anything with firebase/google cloud you have to jump around to multiple guides all over the place, out of the blue knowing all kinds of things to make any progress whatsoever).

Edit:
The reason I didn't find the service account was because google cloud had selected a project that had a similar name as the firebase project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the contents of `myfile.json`, notice three fields: `project_id`, `client_email` and `private_key_id`

These fields tell you the Project ID that the credentials created in, the name of the service account (client_email) and the Key ID.

With that information, you can go to the Google Cloud Console. Log in and select your Project (if you manage more than one Project). Go to IAM -> Service Accounts and find the service account by the `client_email`. Then disable or delete the service account.

There are more advanced things that you can do such as disable a key and create another one (key rotation), but since the Service Account Key JSON file has been leaked, I would delete the service account and create a new one.

Comment: And then to create a new file you do that from firebase rather than the google cloud console. In Settings -> Service accounts you can create a service account, and for some reason (as of this date) "Generate new private key" actually means download the new myfile.json

Comment: @RobinManoli - How do you expect to get the new JSON key file unless you download it?

Comment: I expect "generate" to generate a key. The key can be generated without you downloading it as a .json file. The verb should be "generate and download".

Comment: I was worried how to recreate the Firebase Admin SDK service account, but it turned out that after deleting it, Firebase automatically offers to create a new Firebase Admin SDK service account when visiting the "Project settings > Service accounts" page 

Comment: Also you can delete key by going to the keys tabs 